# jQuery - How to sync multiple animations on a page?

Tags: jquery, events, synchronization, jquery-animate

Please totally ignore the design here, it's WIP.
http://marckremers.com/ltd

I'm using jquery.cycle to animate 6 cards on each page. I'm wondering if there is a way I can have the animation trigger simultaneously so that they aren't out of sync?

Here the link to the plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Thanks,
Marc

Comment: I notice on the plugin page that there is the ability to trigger the effect via a click. Perhaps "synchronize" them by using a setTimeout and calling them all at once? I still feel this would be flawed given the single-threaded nature of JavaScript. That's assuming you can't use $('#element1,#element2,#element3').cycle(...) doesn't already tie them together.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `timeout` to 0 to disable auto advance.  Then call `setInterval` to advance all slides at the same time.

```
$('.card_holder').cycle({ 
    fx:     'scrollVert', 
    timeout: 0                 // disable auto advance
}); 

// Cycle to the next every 4 seconds
setInterval("$('.card_holder').cycle('next')", 4000);
```

**[Click here for a demo](http://pastehtml.com/view/1bv37m1.html)**

Answer (score 0):

You should also have your selector be using IDs instead of classes. It runs a lot faster that way and is less likely to not be synched. In your WP theme, you can set an ID for each one by putting in `id="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>"` where you declare `<div class="wrapper">`. If you do that, you can get rid of the `i` bit.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var projectCycleIDs = '';
var i = 0;

$('.wrapper').each(function() {
    i++;
    $(this).attr('id', i)
    var thisProjectID = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
    if (projectCycleIDs == '') {
        projectCycleIDs = thisProjectID;
    } else {
        projectCycleIDs = projectCycleIDs + ',' + thisProjectID;
    }
});

$(projectCycleIDs).cycle({ 
    fx:     'scrollVert', 
    sync: 1
 });
```

});